# Old cookies vanish when add new cookies angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm try add cookies . It's work well but when I refresh page  and  add new cookies , old cookies disappear , and cookies.length not update . It update after i refresh page . Here is my code

```
vm.cart = [];
vm.add = function(tensp,gia,img){
                    vm.cart.push({tensp:tensp,gia:gia,img:img,sl:1})
                    $cookies.putObject('cart',vm.cart);

        }
```

And display in html .

```
 vm.cookies = $cookies.getObject('cart');
{{vm.cookies.length}}
```

Where is my wrong . Please help me . Here is my plnkr 
https://plnkr.co/edit/StURuPuEBr8ykIUPdvBV?p=preview

Comment: When you add a new value to the same key `cart`, the old value is overwritten. If you have no key other than `cart`, the cookie length should always be 1. That's my guess based on your snippet. If you can create a simple working demo to demonstrate the problem, I'll have a look.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/StURuPuEBr8ykIUPdvBV?p=preview here is plnkr I create . I think you right with my problem . How can I add new value to same key and no overwritten . You can see my problem when you click button add , and hit space (plnkr reload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you refresh the page. `vm.cart` will be set to `[]`. And when you click "Add", one item will be added to `vm.cart`. `vm.cart` now contains one item. When `vm.cart` is put into cookies, all existing items in cookies will be overwritten.

If you want to keep all items in cookies, put items directly to cookies and retrieve items directly from cookies as follows

```
var item = {
  id: id,
  masp: masp,
  tensp: tensp
};

var cart = $cookies.getObject('cart');

if (cart) {
  var items = JSON.parse(cart);
  items.push(item);

  $cookies.putObject('cart', JSON.stringify(items));
} else {
  $cookies.putObject('cart', JSON.stringify([ item ]));
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JE4U5I?p=preview).

Comment: Perfect . Thank you so much !